# mapping list to list[dict] using react

Tags: reactjs

Whats the most elegant way of mapping a list into a list of dictionaries n at a time using react?

```
["a", "b", "c"] => [{0:"a", 1:"b"}, {0:"c"}]
```

Comment: What do you mean _"using react"_? This seems to be a basic JS task, iterating in groups of a given length, in which case see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28359919/3001761. Also note in JS nomenclature those are _objects_, not _dictionaries_, and _arrays_, not _lists_.

Comment: What is the algorithm behind your example?

Comment: Literally splitting a list into groups of n, where each item corresponds to a unique dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  acc.push({ [currentIndex]: currentValue });

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Here's a great Twitter post that explains how various array methods work:

https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/741089564329054208

Comment: I don't see how that works by grouping n at a time.

Comment: Hmm I see, I missed that part.